# How easy is it to put my C++ demo onto an iPhone?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, directx

I have access to both OSX and Windows. I have built my demo in Visual Studio 2010 using C++ and DirectX 10. I have read that C++ can be run on the iPhone using XCode, but that any input has to handled in objective-c.

At present there is no input so that's not an issue right now.

What are the steps I would have to take to get it running on the iPhone?

also - was not quite sure how to tag this question. by all means edit them if they're wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run C++ code fine on an iPhone. I've released a couple games which have a large C++ component. Of course, the graphics will need to be redone.

Likely you'll need a little bit of Objective-C++ code to communicate between the UI layer and the underlying engine.

Answer (score 1):

There's no DirectX on iOS (being that it's made by Microsoft) so any code that calls DirectX is going to need to be ported over to something that can be run on iOS, like OpenGL.

Other than that you'll be treating your code like a library. With a layer of objective-c that sets up the app, and calls the necessary parts of your C++ code.

Comment: but other than changing the DX10 calls to OGLES calls for example, and then wrapping it in objective C that's it right? My pure C++ code should work just the same?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing all of your code, but based on what you described I would say yes.